# Zxing compiled 2.0 with Java 1.5

Tags: java, zxing

Hi I have to used the `javase` zxing module. 
I have read the [zxing getting start](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted) and I have tried to compile `core` and javase modules (with JDK 1.5.0_22)

I run ant script in core folder, I have this error:

```
[javac] javac: invalid target release: 6
```

If I modify the ant script `build.xml` in core folder replacing `target=6` with `target=5` and `source=6` with `source=5` I have 42 errors of compilation:

```
init:

build:
    [javac] Compiling 169 source files to D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\build
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\MultiFormatReader.j
ava:52: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\MultiFormatReader.j
ava:66: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\MultiFormatReader.j
ava:157: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\MultiFormatWriter.j
ava:40: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\MultiFormatWriter.j
ava:48: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\aztec\AztecReader.j
ava:52: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\aztec\AztecReader.j
ava:57: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\aztec\AztecReader.j
ava:89: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\datamatrix\DataMatr
ixReader.java:57: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\datamatrix\DataMatr
ixReader.java:62: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\datamatrix\DataMatr
ixReader.java:89: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\datamatrix\detector
\Detector.java:444: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\maxicode\MaxiCodeRe
ader.java:58: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\maxicode\MaxiCodeRe
ader.java:63: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\maxicode\MaxiCodeRe
ader.java:84: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\multi\ByQuadrantRea
der.java:46: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\multi\ByQuadrantRea
der.java:52: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\multi\ByQuadrantRea
der.java:95: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\multi\GenericMultip
leBarcodeReader.java:55: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\multi\GenericMultip
leBarcodeReader.java:60: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\qrcode\QRCodeReader
.java:61: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\qrcode\QRCodeReader
.java:66: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\qrcode\QRCodeReader
.java:93: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\multi\qrcode\QRCode
MultiReader.java:47: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\multi\qrcode\QRCode
MultiReader.java:52: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\qrcode\detector\Fin
derPatternFinder.java:557: method does not override a method from its superclass

    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\qrcode\detector\Fin
derPatternFinder.java:573: method does not override a method from its superclass

    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\multi\qrcode\detect
or\MultiFinderPatternFinder.java:80: method does not override a method from its
superclass
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\oned\OneDReader.jav
a:47: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\oned\OneDReader.jav
a:53: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\oned\OneDReader.jav
a:87: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\oned\OneDimensional
CodeWriter.java:40: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\oned\OneDimensional
CodeWriter.java:53: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\oned\UPCAWriter.jav
a:36: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\oned\UPCAWriter.jav
a:42: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\pdf417\PDF417Reader
.java:53: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\pdf417\PDF417Reader
.java:58: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\pdf417\PDF417Reader
.java:76: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\pdf417\encoder\PDF4
17Writer.java:32: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\pdf417\encoder\PDF4
17Writer.java:41: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\qrcode\QRCodeWriter
.java:40: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\src\com\google\zxing\qrcode\QRCodeWriter
.java:47: method does not override a method from its superclass
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]    ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 42 errors

BUILD FAILED
D:\ZXing-2.0\zxing-2.0\core\build.xml:37: Compile failed; see the compiler error
 output for details.
```

Thanks

Comment: I have added the log error in the message.

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: Pretty simple: as you can see, the library requires Java 6. You can't just change that to Java 5 and expect it to work.

Comment: I don't know the I have to remove the source attribute in javac tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) version 6 with options `-source 6` and `-target 5`! See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927594/is-is-possible-to-build-java-code-using-jdk-1-6-to-run-on-jre-1-5).

**UPDATE:** remove the `-source` option, that should work using a `javac` version 6

```
> javac -version
javac 1.6.0_22
> javac -target 5 ...
```

Comment: I have tried: this is the error: [javac] javac: source release 6 requires target release 1.6

Answer (score 3):

This is Java 6 syntax which cannot be parsed by Java 5 javac.

Install and use a Java 6 JDK which has a Java 6 javac.

(If you cannot do that, you can experiment with using the Eclipse compiler which can compile Java 6 sources using a Java 5 JVM - http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-ant_javac_adapter.htm - you will also need to download an appropriate version of ecj.jar)

Comment: `@Override` was introduced since JDK 5. So it can be compiled with JDK 1.5

Comment: It is true, but with JDK 5 don't compile

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman the semantics of @-Override has changed between Java 5 and Java 6.  Check out the usage in interfaces.

Comment: the source can be 1.7 and compiled to a 1.5 target. remember to use `bootclasspath`. annotations don't exist in the generated class files :)

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for zxing-2.1. I did the following changes:

build.xml:

```
<target name="build" depends="init">
  <mkdir dir="build"/>
  <javac srcdir="src"
     destdir="build"
     source="5"
     target="5"
```

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>5</source>
    <target>5</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And was able to compile (mvn clean package) both core & javase with no issues.