# Should the ejb jar be compiled on the same JVM that deploys the JBOSS AS?

Tags: java, deployment, jboss

I have two machines with difference JVM versions (1.6 and 1.5)

I have a JBOSS Server running on the one of JDK1.5. I've created a ejb jar file on the machine of JDK1.6.

When I get to deploy the EJB Jar into the JBOSS(4.3), I get the following error:

```
16:05:41,878 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem creating service jboss.j2ee:service=EJB3,module=ejb1_test.jar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unexpected error during load of: org.daz.TimeServiceBean, msg=Bad version number in .class file
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java - is it possible to choose version number when compile a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207537/java-is-it-possible-to-choose-version-number-when-compile-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run in java 1.5 then you *should* compile in java 1.5 or lower.

Alternatively, if you simply must run JDK 6 then as @Paul Tomblin suggests you can use the -target javac option.  One warning on this though, if you are using any of the new Java 1.6 API features javac 1.6 (e.g. [setting File perms](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean%29)) javac will not complain but you will get errors when running this code in java 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

`javac` has a -target option that allows you to compile to a 1.5 jvm with a 1.6 compiler.  See `javac -help` for details.