# Java desktop app compatibility with 32 bits jre

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

i want to do a stand alone application using sqlite. The application should help to manage an inventory.

1. I need my application runs on pc with the next features:

   - 32 bits windows 7 OS, Java 8 update 25
   - 32 bits windows 7 OS, Java 7 update 25
2. I don't have any administrator permission on computer listed above.
3. My computer has NetbeansIDE 8.2, 64 windows 10 OS, Java 8 update 111, Java SE 8 update 101, Java SE 7 update 79.

Do i need any admin permission to run my app?, What should i do to run my app on 32 bits OS?

Comment: Nope... this is not the way this site works..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will JRE 1.4 support classes compiled with Java 1.5 & 1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710933/will-jre-1-4-support-classes-compiled-with-java-1-5-1-6) To work on 32bit java 7 PC's just compile with 32bit java 7.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Client PCs should have a JRE of a Newer or a similar version of the JDK you used to create the application.

You can create a windows executable using [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) which is able to specify the JRE version and the Architecture.

[image: Launch4J Screenshot]

Please refer to the documentation. You'll get a better understanding.