# How to remove large if-else-if chain

Tags: java, string, optimization, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Long list of if statements in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199646/long-list-of-if-statements-in-java)

I was tasked to work with some code, and there is a giant if-else-if chain (100+ else-ifs) that checks Strings.

What are some good techniques to update this code as to where the if-else-if chain can be shrunken down to something much more manageable.

The chain looks something like this:

```
if(name.equals("abc")){
    do something
} else if(name.equals("xyz")){
    do something different
} else if(name.equals("mno")){
    do something different
} ......
.....
else{ 
   error
}
```

Comment: The command pattern is the way to handle this for sure, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199646/long-list-of-if-statements-in-java/1199677#1199677

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it as-is, other than seeming to be bothersome?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can extract the code in each branch to a separate method, then turn the methods into implementations of a common base interface (let's call it `Handler`). After that, you can fill a `Map<String, Handler>` and just look up and execute the right handler for given string.

Unfortunately the implementation of 100+ subclasses for the interface requires quite a lot of boilerplate code, but currently there is no simpler way in Java to achieve this. Implementing the cases as elements of an `Enum` may help somewhat - [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913495/refactoring-if-else-logic/2913518#2913518). The ideal solution would be using closures / lambdas, but alas we have to wait till Java 8 for that...

Comment: +1  That is my usual approach.  Makes the code clean and easy to extend.  When Java gets lambdas it will make it beautiful.

Comment: What about the fact that you need to keep many Handler instances in the Map that are probably not going to be used?

Comment: Did you measure this with JMH? It would be nice to know at what point the cost of [dynamic dispatch](http://shipilev.net/blog/2015/black-magic-method-dispatch/) is lower than the if-else branching.

Comment: I'm wondering if someone can provide an example of how to simplify this using lambdas (now that Java 8 is out)

Comment: @vivekmore Declare the map with something like `Map<String, Handler> foo = new Map<>();`, and populate the map with something like `foo.put("bar", MyClass::doBar);` assuming that class `Handler` is a functional interface.

Answer (score 9):

Some options / ideas:

- **Leave it as it is** - it's not fundamentally broken, and is reasonably clear and simple to maintain
- **Use a switch statement (if you are using Java 7)** - not sure if this gains you much though
- **Create a HashMap of String to FunctionObjects** where the function objects implement the required behaviour as a method. Then your calling code is just: `hashMap.get(name).doSomething();`
- **Break it into a heirarchy of function calls** by sub-grouping the strings. You could do this by taking each letter in turn, so one branch handles all the names starting with 'a' etc.
- **Refactor** so that you don't pass the name as a String but instead pass a named object. Then you can just do `namedObject.doSomething()`

Answer (score 8):

With Enums, you can have a method per instance.

```
public enum ActionEnum {
   ABC {
      @Override
      void doSomething() {
          System.out.println("Doing something for ABC");    
      }

   },
   XYZ {
      @Override
      void doSomething() {
         System.out.println("Doing something for XYZ"); 
      }
   };

   abstract void doSomething();
}

public class MyActionClass {

    public void myMethod(String name) {
        ActionEnum.valueOf("ABC").doSomething();
    }

}
```

It is still kinda messy (big enum with 100+ entries, even it all it does is dispatching), but may avoid the HashMap initialization code (100+ puts is also messy in my opinion).

And yet another option (for documentation purposes) would be reflection:

```
public interface Action {
    void doSomething();
}

public class ABCAction implements Action {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Doing something for ABC");      
    }
}

public class MyActionClass {

    void doSomethingWithReflection(String name) {
        try {
            Class<? extends Action> actionClass = Class.
                forName("actpck."+ name + "Action").asSubclass(Action.class);
            Action a = actionClass.newInstance();
            a.doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Catch exceptions individually and do something useful. 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Each approach has it's trade offs:

- HashMap = Fast + Kinda messy ("set-up" code with hundred of puts)
- Enum = Fast + Kinda messy 2 (huge file).
- Reflection = Slower + runtime error prone, but provides clean separation without resorting to clunky big HashMap.

Answer (score 7):

Like Matt Ball said in his comment, you can use a command pattern. Define a collection of Runnable classes:

```
Runnable task1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { /* do something */ }
};
Runnable task2 = // etc.
```

Then you can use a map from your keys to runnables:

```
Map<String,Runnable> taskMap = new HashMap<String,Runnable>();
taskMap.put("abc", task1);
taskMap.put("xyz", task2);
// etc.
```

Finally, replace the if-else chain with:

```
Runnable task = taskMap.get(name);
if (task != null) {
    task.run();
} else {
    // default else action from your original chain
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the switch statement , but Switch statements with String cases have been implemented in [Java SE 7](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/)

the best solution is to use the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Comment: it's not a bad idea but make a pattern of command i think that should be a better solution

Answer (score -1):

This is a popular [Arrow Anti-Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern) and Jeff discusses some approaches to handle this very nicely in his post [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern).

Comment: This is NOT the Arrow anti-pattern.