# Android project using Eclipse gives error: Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, switch-statement, adt

I was working on an android project using eclipse and suddenly i started to get this error:

> Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted.

I tried every solution in previous similar issues but none of them worked for me...

I have Tried fixing the project and setting the JDK compliance level to 1.7 in both my project and for all project.

I am using ADT Build: v22.2.1-833290 and Eclipse:

```
String text = mService.getString();
switch (text) {
    case Protocols.REQUEST_SEND_MESSAGE:
        publishProgress("sent");
        break;
    case Protocols.RESPONSE_OK:
        mService.sendMessage("mesasage");   
        publishProgress("sent");  
        break;              
    default:
        break;
}
```

What's going on?

Comment: Would you please provide some code

Comment: Code has been added, but i guess @beworker's answer is logical. i can just use `if / else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `switch` / `case` with `String` objects, which is only available in Java 1.7 or higher. Android ADT requires Java 1.6. This means you cannot use `switch` with `String` construct. Just replace it with `if` / `else`.

Replace your code with this.

```
String text=mService.getString();
if (Protocols.REQUEST_SEND_MESSAGE.equals(text)) {
    publishProgress("sent");
} else if (Protocols.RESPONSE_OK.equals(text)) {
    mService.sendMessage("mesasage");
    publishProgress("sent"); 
}
```

Another option would be to create an `enum` and put all Protocol constants into there. Then you will be able to use `switch` / `case` with `enum` values.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot. But is there a way to get around this error ? update ? or plugin ? maybe a new Eclipse or ADT version or update ?

Comment: Yea, i already have it implemented as `if / else` but the code was getting a bit messy because there a lot more of cases so i thought of making it neater by a `switch` case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to refactor this code to if / else all the time until the time Android starts supporting Java 1.7. No other options are available.

Comment: Another option would be to create an enum from Protocol constants. Then you can use enum values in switch / case. But Android performance guide does not suggest to use enums because they are memory intensive.

Comment: I will look into that too.

Answer (score 2):

As the answer below gives more details, switch statement on String objects is a new feature introduced in Java 1.7. Unfortunatelly Android requires version 1.6 or 1.5.  :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367642/1572408

Comment: Thanks, there is a helpful link to check later on in that post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349883/how-to-remove-large-if-else-if-chain)