# What are the native typesafe enum patterns?

Tags: java

I am a newbie to java, i want to learn about the native typesafe enum patterns? can anybody help me?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have a specific question about how to use them?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: i want to know the difference between typesafe enum patterns and native type-safe enum patterns.

Comment: @ChandanMithun: What do you mean by "...typesafe enum patterns..." and "...native type-safe enum patterns..."? The best practice and pattern for enums in Java is to use the built-in (is that what you mean by "native"?) `enum` concept, which has been in the language for years.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Thank you, now i got the clear understanding

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092015/advantages-of-javas-enum-over-the-old-typesafe-enum-pattern

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/why-and-what-for-java-enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to know the difference between typesafe enum patterns and native type-safe enum patterns.

A type-safe enum pattern is a design / implementation pattern that provides something similar to native enums.  Since, Java 5.0 and later support native `enum` types ([tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)), there is no real need to know how to do this.  Just use native `enum` types.

If you are curious about how it *used to be done*, read this: [Alternative to enum in Java 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038321/alternative-to-enum-in-java-1-4)

(A *native* typesafe enum pattern is a contradiction in terms.  Java's native enum construct is a first class programming language construct ... not a design pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `enum`s; details [in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).

Comment: Sending a *newbie* to the JLS is not going to help him very much!

Comment: @assylias: I'm not sure I agree, if more people read the JLS early on... :-) But in any case, pointing out that Java has `enum` as a first-class concept (now) should be helpful.