# OAuth 2.0 client in Java 1.4

Tags: oauth-2.0, java1.4

I have to implement an OAuth 2.0 client program to retrieve access token in Java 1.4. Using org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client-0.31.jar and org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common-0.31.jar was not successful since Java 1.4 does not support Enums. Please suggest a method.

Comment: Why java 1.4.? Is that a limitation on your servers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038321/alternative-to-enum-in-java-1-4 might be useful

Comment: Yes. Its due to limitations in environment. Is there an oauth2 client library that supports java 1.4?

Comment: What's your client type ?

Comment: Hi KcDoD, Im developing a REST client where access token should be retrieved under OAuth 2.0 framework.